# How to retrieve all records for an entity in Dynamics CRM 4.0?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Is there a way to retrieve all of the records for a given entity using the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 SDK?  I want the equivalent of:

```
SELECT foo
FROM new_bar
```

... where `new_bar` is the name of the entity.

This seems trivial, but I can't find any examples on how to retrieve *all* of the records for a given entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want to retrieve `all` the records for a given entity, you need to used the `Paging Cookie`, otherwise you will get maximum 5000 records.

You can find an example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151070.aspx